# How to Add a Client System To a Server

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2

I have recently installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on one my system and now want to add my client to that server.

Almost all the systems have been added but two of them are refusing to add by showing this error

```
a domain controller for the domain xxxx could not be contacted ..
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have Active Directory issues, you should first check DNS. If everything looks OK there, you should ask yourself `"What DNS issue did I miss?"` and then check DNS again.

I'll bet my bonnet that you aren't using the Domain Controller as the DNS server on the clients that are having a problem. Set the IP for the DNS servers on the Windows clients having the issue to use the Domain Controllers and the Domain Controllers alone for DNS.

Comment: I think a better question is "did he configure a Windows Domain/Active Directory in the first place".  That question seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: @Driftpeasant He says `"All most all the systems have been added but two of them are refusing to add by showing this error"` which leads me to believe that he does have AD installed. What you said was my first thought, though.

Comment: Ah, fair point.  I missed that bit.

Comment: then any one have a solution... out of these two one now has been connected after a try of 20 times..

Comment: finally what i did is just removed the previous domain name which was same as the current and changed the domain to workgroup and then again connected.. that worked.. but still this solution has no affect on the last pc

Comment: eh? It worked when you put your domain name in the workgroup field? This would imply that you are trying to log in using a local username or something similar. MarkM is right. You have a DNS problem. Can you do 'ping mydomain.local' from the problem machine? Does it resolve to the IP of the domain controller. The fact that the other machine suddenly joined looks like you have an external dns server + the dc configured as dns servers for this PC.